# Subsampling videos to save every Nth frame

Tags: python, matlab, video, subsampling

I have thousands of 30sec/20fps/.avi videos (so 600 frames total per video). I need to automate subsampling these videos in order to save every 100th frame (every 5 seconds). Any picture format is fine.

Is there an easy way to do this in either Matlab (R2015b) or Python+libraries?

Comment: I would think that ffmpeg would be a much better and more efficient tool for this.

Comment: Can that perform this across multiple subdirectories automatically?

Comment: Sure. With a bit of bash or python scripting it should be able to do that. I recommend searching and trying it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MATLAB:

you can use `VideoWriter` object or `imwrite`, depends on the desired output format:

```
vin = VideoReader('vid1.mp4');
vout = VideoWriter('vid-out.mp4');
framenum = 0;
everyNframe = 100;
vout.open();
while vin.hasFrame
    frame = vin.readFrame;
    if rem(framenum,everyNframe) == 0
        vout.writeVideo(frame);
        % OR
        imwrite(frame, [num2str(framenum,'%04i') '.jpg']);
        disp(framenum)
    end
    framenum = framenum + 1;
end
vout.close();
```

another option the ffwd the input video to the next desired frame is by setting `vin.CurrentTime`, but for some reason it is slower than simply read 100 frames.

Comment: I'm getting the error `Undefined variable "v" or class "v.readFrame".

Error in testsubsample (line 7)
    frame = v.readFrame;` I should have specified that the video format is `.avi`, is that the reason?

Comment: my bad... fixed it. 'avi' is just fine for matlab

Comment: thanks, but I'm getting another error now. It's kind of long so I'll add it to my original post

Comment: my bad again... fixed it again, im confused today... :)

Answer (score 3):

In python, you could use `scikit-video` combined with `numpy` to do this:

```
import skvideo.io

def subsample_and_write(filename, out_filename, n_steps):
    video_mat = skvideo.io.vread(filename)  # returns a NumPy array
    video_mat = video_mat[::n_steps]  # subsample
    skvideo.io.vwrite(out_filename, video_mat)
```